# JSON String is not validated using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I've a JSON String, for which I'm trying to check whether its a JSON Object or not using jQuery. I've used

```
try {
   var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonString);
} 
   catch (e) {
    // handle error 
}
```

and using `json = eval("{" + jsonString + "}");` too..

Here is my fiddle. Can any one let me know what's the issue in the JSON format?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/1735/)

Comment: It’s `eval("(" + jsonString + ")")`. Parentheses to make it an expression, not brackets to make it… something.

Comment: @minitech, Can you update the same in JSFiddle and check? because it still says not valid json

Comment: Do you mean that you are not getting an exception no matter how malformed your JSON is? Or what's your problem then? Your fiddle code does not even try to do it the right way (with `parseJSON`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when using `eval` to parse trusted JSON, you wrap the literal in parentheses to force it to be parsed as an expression – not curly braces, which actually don’t change anything about how it’s evaluated when using `eval`. Since `JSON.parse` enjoys fairly wide support now, however, use that.

Next, there are escape sequences in your JSON.

```
"password":"RwKmzDQppBSLz61Ciw5IZQ\u003d\u003d\r\n"
```

When you place these in a JavaScript string literal, they’re parsed as the characters they represent, making the JSON invalid. You’ll need to double-escape them for testing, as in:

```
'…"password":"RwKmzDQppBSLz61Ciw5IZQ\\u003d\\u003d\\r\\n"…'
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/1741/)

Comment: Thanks..Have you changed the Object data itself?

Comment: @Nizam: No, assuming you’re using a string literal for debugging. `'\r\n'` in JavaScript represents the bytes [13, 10]. If you obtain the string from an external source, you’ll have the right characters (backslash, r, backslash, n).

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var response=jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonString);

if(typeof(response) =='object')
{
  //It is JSON
}
```